# MySQL query slow (DISTINCT WHERE on indexed column)

Tags: mysql, performance

Specs:

- MySQL version: 5.6.19 (Ubuntu)
- Also tried MariaDB, and got the same problem

Table:

```
CREATE TABLE `x` (
    `id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `a` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    `time` DECIMAL(16,6) NOT NULL,

    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    INDEX `a` (`a`),
    INDEX `time` (`time`),
    INDEX `time_a` (`time`, `a`)
)
COLLATE='utf8_unicode_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT=298846
;
```

Query:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT `a`) c
FROM `x`
WHERE `time` >= (UNIX_TIMESTAMP()- (60 * 24));
```

This query is very SLOW, if there are a lot of rows with `time` in the given range. Also note that while there might be a lot of matching rows (thousands or tens of thousands or more), the amount of `DISTINCT` `a`'s is always rather small (a few hundred).

The query is fast (basically instant), no matter the size of the table, when:

1. there are only few rows with `time` in the given range or when
2. there is no `WHERE` part (because of the index on `a`)

That makes me think that it is somehow unable to use the index on `a` when counting, even though `EXPLAIN` mentions all three indices in `possibly_keys`.

The issue remains even if:

- `time` is of type `BIGINT` or `DATETIME` (with corresponding changes to the query)
- `ENGINE=MyISAM`

Any suggestions?

Comment: Try count without diatinct keyword. Is it fast?

Comment: @GiorgiNakeuri It's a little bit faster than counting with `DISTINCT`, but still slow. However counting non-distinctly is even slow without the `WHERE`: `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM x` is also relatively slow (but still almost 1.5x to 2x as fast as `SELECT COUNT (*) FROM x WHERE ...`).

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT `a`)
    FROM `x`;
```

will leapfrog through `INDEX(a)`.  See `EXPLAIN FORMAT=JSON SELECT ...` and look for `"using_index_for_group_by": true`.  This makes it quite fast when there are only a small number of distinct `a` values.

I suspect that using the `WHERE` clause will say `"using_index_for_group_by": "scanning"`, implying that it is less efficient.  I suspect the implementers did the single-key case, but not the multi-key case.

Was that the entire table definition?  I see `AUTO_INCREMENT` without any index for it.  What's up?  About the only difference between MyISAM and InnoDB that is relevant to this discussion is the handling of the `PRIMARY KEY`.

The datatype of `time` is probably not significant.

If I have not satisfied your "Any suggestions?" question, please rephrase the question.

Comment: 1) Thanks for noticing the `PRIMARY KEY` thing. I added it. 2) NOTE: We did change to MariaDB now, but the problem remains. 3) `EXPLAIN` does not yield any `using_index_for_group_by` information, but it does yield the following (amongst others): `"key": 'time_a', "used_key_parts": ["time"], "rows": 896537, "filtered": 100, "using_index": true`. The result count is `17064` (given I ask for `time > 0`, so it still matches everything), the table has 1.8M rows and the query takes about 2 seconds. Without the `WHERE`, it takes 0.5 seconds (yielding the same results in this test case).

Comment: MariaDB may have not picked up the latest `FORMAT=JSON` features from Oracle.

Comment: Use this technique to get more insight into what is going on:  `FLUSH STATUS; SELECT ...; SHOW SESSION STATUS LIKE 'Handler%';`

Comment: Thanks for helping me out, Rick! So the `SESSION_STATUS` is all 0, except for `Handler_commit`, `Handler_read_key` which are `1`, and `Handler_read_next` which is equal to the total number of rows in the table.

Comment: The 'commit' seems to always be 1.  'read_key=1' probably indicates an indexed lookup to get started.  Your 'read_next' implies one full table scan -- that is, no leapfrogging, no index usage, etc.  Try it with the other other variants of your `SELECT` to see what they are doing.

Comment: If the `WHERE` is gone, I get `read_key = read_next = 0` and `read_first = read_last = 1`

Answer (score 0):

Try using index hinting to force the query to use the index you want it to use.

`` SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT `a`) c
FROM `x` FORCE INDEX (the_index_you_want_to_use) 
WHERE `time` >= (UNIX_TIMESTAMP()- (60 * 24)); ``

Comment: Tried all kinds of combinations of the three indices in the `FORCE INDEX` clause. Did not speed things up.

Comment: Don't use `FORCE INDEX` unless you have good reason (eg, `EXPLAIN`) that proves that it is using the wrong index.

Answer (score 0):

It is best not to do any computations in such where clauses.

```
var unixtime = UNIX_TIMESTAMP()- (60 * 24)

SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT `a`) c
FROM `x` FORCE INDEX (the_index_you_want_to_use) 
WHERE `time` >= unixtime
```

Comment: Sadly this did not help... (NOTE: `VAR` does not seem to exist in MySQL. Changed the first line to: `SET @unixtime := UNIX_TIMESTAMP()- (60 * 24);`)

Comment: I would assume that the optimizer is smart enough to do constant folding (since the `WHERE` clause is independent of anything else, it can be handled as a constant)

Answer (score 0):

If I had to guess, the problem is types.  `UNIX_TIMESTAMP()` returns an unsigned integer.  Your `time` variable is `decimal`.  These are *not* the same thing.  And, type mismatches can confuse the optimizer.

It sounds like the table is big, so changing the type is not feasible (you might want to test this, though, if you can by selecting the data into a new table with the right types).

The following might help:

```
WHERE `time` >= cast(UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - (60 * 24) as unsigned);
```

You could also declare a local unsigned variable and store the "constant" in the variable to see if that fixes the performance problem.

Finally, if the index on `time, a` is not being used, try this variation of the query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as c
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT a
      FROM `x` 
      WHERE `time` >= CAST(unixtime - 24 * 60 as unsigned)
     ) ax
```

I have seen this re-structuring improve performance on other databases, although not on MySQL.

Comment: Since `time` is of type `DECIMAL(16, 6)`, I tried: `WHERE time >= CAST(UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - 2400 * 60 as DECIMAL(16, 6))`. No luck though...

Comment: As I mentioned in my original post, I also tried different types for `time` and that did not help either...

Comment: Separating it into multiple `SELECT`s does not help either